# Azure ServiceBus Dynamic activation like MSMQ

Tags: azure, msmq, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, msmqintegrationbinding

We have an existing application that uses MSMQ and WCF Service to receive messages from the queue and process them.

The WCF service is configured as a WAS service in IIS and uses msmqIntegrationBinding binding. The service is called automatically when a message is sent to the queue.

Now we need to implement the same using Azure Service Bus as part of transition to the cloud.

I checked this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/10/07/using-service-bus-queues-with-wcf.aspx article.

The service gets called when a message is sent to the queue but it uses ChannelFactory and a contract assembly from the service in my client application.

In MSMQ binding, my client doesn't need to know anything about the service. It is automatically inferred since the name of the service and name of the queue need to exactly the same.

In simple words, I need to be able to send a msg to Service bus and IIS/WAS should take care of calling the appropriate service just like the way it works with MSMQ.

Is it possible to have MSMQ like activation with Azure Service bus ?